# gimp bucket fill, fills wrong color

Tags: gimp

I've made sprite sheets many times before, but now gimp is messing up. Bucket fill, colours a space gray rather than teal. I cant figure out how to fix it, (I havent tried purging gimp yet). I made a video of the problem, but It would appear I cant provide that directly. [Here is a link to the video of the problem:](http://nanocluster.umeche.maine.edu/g.ogv)

Comment: Have a look at the title of you image window, and figure out what all of its parts mean. Then you will also be able to answer your question yourself.

Comment: Not everyone who makes use of this kind of software is aware of what these different modes are or that they even exist.

Comment: You video link is broken. Why don't you use Youtube?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Indexed mode

The Indexed command converts your image to indexed mode. See indexed colors in the Glossary for more information about Indexed Color Mode.

You can access this command from the image menubar through Image → Mode → Indexed, and in my case, set it to RGB.

[image: Some Toasters ready for Blitting in an assets page]